# annotation are not allowed here IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, annotations

[image: Test annotation are not allowed here]

When I build a test JUnit to do some test in IDEA, I was facing the problem above and I do not know why.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is not just a false positive because the syntax is not complete? (your ending } class is not written).

Answer (score 3):

Definitely syntax related. In my case I was missing brackets in a method signature (facepalm!). Once you complete the method, the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The *annotation not allowed* error is displayed because your class does not contain methods, so it's not able to find where its going to be used, so this error displayed.

I have added small code snippet. Just copy and paste then try this... it will work.

```
package com.sel1;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JunitTest1 {

@BeforeClass

public void Testme()
{
    System.out.println("test");
}

}
```